# APNS token collision, stored in Postgres

Tags: ios, objective-c, postgresql, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I use push notifications and store device tokens like I assume everyone else does. First I transform them into a string my app:

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[token description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Then I PUT them to my server, where ActiveRecord stores them in a `character varying(255)` column:

```
Device.where(:token => device_token, :username => username).first_or_create!(:model => model)
```

I have a validation that ensures no two tokens are the same, **which I understand should always be the case:**

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :token
end
```

However, I've started to see validation errors for token uniqueness:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Token has already been taken`

Manual query in psql confirms that a device is trying to register with a token already in the table under a different user. Isn't this supposed to be impossible? Is something in the way I'm transforming tokens truncating them? I checked every code example I could find when the problem first occurred and everyone seems to use the method I've listed in the first code sample.

Comment: Sounds more likely to be an application bug where some shared state isn't properly cleared. But it hardly seems impossible that APNS could have quirks or unspecified behaviours like "unique within <x> time period then cycles". I'd want to try capturing raw incoming data and next time you see a dup, look at what the client actually sent to verify it's what you expect.

Comment: I can't capture anything on the client end, but I've saved the input for every duplicate and nothing seems amiss. They're just genuinely sending up an identifier that's already been used.

Comment: Time to talk to Apple support I guess, then, and follow up here when(if) you ever hear anything. I won't hold my breath.

Comment: How can you tell that it's not the same device with a different user? Say, if they've uninstalled the app and reinstalled it?

Comment: My account identifier stays the same across installs, and the same device token showed up for different accounts. I was also under the impression that device tokens stayed the same, but that doesn't change the fact that for two different user accounts the same token showed up.

Comment: device tokens have an expiration date. thats why apple suggests to query for the token on each run of the app and update your server if it has changed. are you completely sure the your account identifier stays the same across installs? did you test this good enough? how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can happen that a device tries to register with a token already in the table under a different user if someone logs out and then logs in with a different account.

I would do the following on the server for a user `user` and a token string `token` (assuming that only one user can be logged in on one device at a time):

1. Check if there is a `Device` for `token_string`.
2. If there is no device, create one for `token_string` and `user`.
3. If there is a device and its user is not `user`, update its user to `user`.

That way, the push notifications will be sent for the last user that logged in on the device.

Concerning your way of transforming the `NSData` to a hex string on the device, you should not rely on `-[NSData description]`. Better do it programmatically (typed in, not tested):

```
- (NSString *)hexStringForData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUInteger length = data.length;
    const char *bytes = data.bytes;
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [result appendFormat:@"%02x", bytes[i] & 0xff];
    }
    return [result copy];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll wager a guess at this one, but take it for what it's for, a guess.

When iOS devices are restored from backups, or when they are "restored" onto new devices, say, someone upgrading from a iPhone 4 to iPhone 5, or when someone gives their iPhone to their wife or sells it on eBay, you will get duplicated/redundant/confusing device data.  I've definitely seen that happen, but not specifically with APNS tokens.

Here is what the [APNS docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) have to say about it:

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every
>   time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider
>   has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a
>   device or computer other than the one that the backup was created for
>   (for example, the user migrates data to a new device or computer), he
>   or she must launch the application at least once for it to receive
>   notifications again. If the user restores backup data to a new device
>   or computer, or reinstalls the operating system, the device token
>   changes. Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your
>   provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it.
>   If your application has previously registered, calling
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in the operating system
>   passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring
>   additional overhead.

So, I'm not looking at your code, but it seems likely that your "duplicate" tokens have to do with some combination of not registering every time, some kind of caching, and device restoration.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what happens when a device registers. It sends your server a POST on the following:

```
/passkit/v1/devices/<deviceID>/registrations/<typeID>/<serial#>
```

And within the JSON payload is the `push_token`.
What matters is both the `deviceID` and `push_token`. As far as Apple is concerned, you communicate with the device through Apple's system with the `push_token` and nothing else.

As for the `deviceID`, it is the actual physical device that is used. The fact that the device might want to register multiple times is irrelevant, and your code should simply update the `push_token` in your DB based on the latest registration attempt. That's about it.